# Typescript: Iterate over a module exported identifiers and validate them against some rules

Tags: typescript

I have a Typescript application that allows a user to set a path to a Typescript module in which i expect him to export some functions with the following specifications:

1. the first argument of the function should be of type: `string`, `boolean` or a `number`
2. the return type of the function should be of type `string`.

I have to somehow inspect module exports, their types and go further in detail like if it is a function, how many arguments it gets and what are the arguments and what are their types. This validation should happen before the exported identifiers are actually used by the app. What is the easiest way to do this before i need to traverse a typescript parser's `AST`.

Comment: Are you importing this module at compile time or runtime?

Comment: @JCOlivares i'm not going to load the module dynamically if it does not comply with some rules. It is a validation check before loading the module. Think of it as a core app and a plugin.